# Does conda env support development dependencies?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Does conda allow you to install a dependency into an environment as a development dependency?

I'm thinking of something like how bower does this with `--save-dev`

Comment: What is the difference between a regular dependency and a development dependency? For those not familiar with bower, what does `--save-dev` do?

Comment: @darthbith I am not familiar with bower, but `npm` also has a `--save-dev` flag. `npm` not only installs a package, but at the same time, updates `pacakge.json`, the equivalent to conda's `environment.yml`. `package.json` tracks two types of dependencies: those used in production and those used also by developers (e.g. a testing framework). When `npm` is asked to install whatever is specified in `package.json`, it will install all of the listed dependencies, unless its `--production` flag is specified; in that case, it will only install those that did not use the `--save-dev` flag.

Comment: @xverges Unfortunately, I don't think `environment.yml` and `package.json` are equivalent. The former must be manually managed by the user, whereas the latter (IIUC) is automatically updated when `npm install` is used. In any case, `conda` doesn't have these flags. You're better off creating several `environment.yml` files, I think

Comment: @darthbith Maybe your "use different `environment.yml` files" should be turned into an answer that the OP can accept?

Answer (score 5):

AFAICT, no, it does not.  This repo represents work around options that might be useful elsewhere:

- https://github.com/dazza-codes/conda_container

In short, it supplements a conda install with subsequent pip installs from a `requirements.txt` and/or a `requirements.dev` file.  Since there can be inconsistencies in conda vs. pip packages (like different name variants etc.), there are use cases for having a combination of conda and pip.  Also conda can support a `pip` array in an `environment.yml` file but the version specs for conda vs. pip packages are not compatible.  Liberal use of `pip check` is recommended for any combination of packages from different packaging systems.